# Callable function not really callable?

Tags: python, function, methods, callable, paraview

I am using ParaView-5.4.1 under Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

I have an object `r` of class `PVDReader` (in `pvpython`, but this is likely irrelevant).
For the method `TimestepValues` of that class

```
>>> callable(r.TimestepValues)
True

>>> type(r.TimestepValues)
<class 'paraview.servermanager.VectorProperty'>

>>> r.TimestepValues
[0.0, 0.002]

>>> r.TimestepValues()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/res/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 681, in __call__
    raise RuntimeError ("Cannot invoke this property")
RuntimeError: Cannot invoke this property

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(r.TimestepValues)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/santiago/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: [0.0, 0.002] is not a Python function
```

So, on one hand, it is callable.
On the other hand, it behaves as if it were not.

**How can this be understood?**
**Is this a bug?**

---

**tl;dr** PS: Other more generic methods behave similarly (but not the same). E.g., compare with `__class__`:

```
>>> callable(r.__class__)
True

>>> type(fluid_pr_reader.__class__)
<type 'type'>        <-- Rather obvious, just for completitude of the comparison with above

>>> r.__class__
<class 'paraview.servermanager.PVDReader'>

>>> r.__class__()
<paraview.servermanager.PVDReader object at 0x7f57ed56fd10>    <-- No error here

>>> inspect.getargspec(r.__class__)
Traceback (most recent call last):     <-- Same error here
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/res/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <class 'paraview.servermanager.PVDReader'> is not a Python function
```

---

**EDIT**: The result is the same if I do not access it as a straight property prior to accessing it as a callable

```
>>> callable(r.TimestepValues)
True
>>> r.TimestepValues()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/res/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 681, in __call__
    raise RuntimeError ("Cannot invoke this property")
RuntimeError: Cannot invoke this property
```

Comment: But is it callable right before you access it as a callable? Accessing it as a straight property possibly changes the type before you try to call it as a method.

Comment: @MatsLindh - Yes, it is. Please see edit.

Comment: `r.TimestepValues` IS a callable object.  You are *successfully calling it*.  The implementation of calls to this object just happens to contain the line `raise RuntimeError ("Cannot invoke this property")`.  (There is apparently some circumstance where calling this type of object actually does something useful, but I don't know enough about this module to have any idea what it might be.)

Comment: @jasonharper - That makes sense... Why would anyone want to define a callable method, only to raise an error when it is called? Due to inheritance to/from other classes? Setting up code for future versions? Any other possible reason?